# Play2, scala: how to use controller result from another controller?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have an application, that used play 2.3.8, scala and (if it matter) play-auth.

Have a controller, with method:

```
def foo(id: Long) = StackAction(AuthorityKey -> Everybody) { implicit request =>
  //code forming json   
  Ok(json) 
}
```

How can I get that json from another controller?
I try something, but without success:

```
def bar(id : Long) = StackAction(AuthorityKey -> Everybody){ implicit request =>
  val futureResponse = AnotherController.foo(id).apply(request)
  val result = Await.result(futureResponse, Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).duration)
  Logger.debug("_______________________" + result.body) //dont't know how to convert that to json
  //handle json there
  Ok(newResult)
}
```

How to do that right?

Comment: The result body is an `Enumerator[Array[Byte]]`, which might not actually be done enumerating. You'd have to force it to enumerate the data by pushing to an `Iteratee`. Something like `result.body |>>> Iteratee.foreach(println)` -- but that will still print out the bytes, so you'd have to convert to `String`, and it will probably be chunked. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: By the way, making controllers dependent to each other is not the best idea. You can put the common logic somewhere and use it from controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 def bar(id : Long) = StackAction(AuthorityKey -> Everybody){ implicit request =>

      val futureResponse: Future[JsValue] = 
          AnotherController.foo(id).apply(request).flatMap{ res =>
              res.body |>>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()
          }.map(bytes => Json.parse(new String(bytes,"utf-8")))

      val json = Await.result(futureResponse, Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).duration)
      Logger.debug("_______________________" + json) //dont't know how to convert that to json
      //handle json there
      Ok(json)
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably want to run `res.body` through the `Results.dechunk` `Enumeratee`. Otherwise, a chunked response will not parse to JSON. ie. `res.body &> Results.dechunk |>>> ....`